# highstock Get all data from current hovered time

Tags: javascript, typescript, highcharts

I feel i've been searching the whole internet now to try and find the easiest way to get all the data from multiple lines, when hovering over a specific time in an highstock chart.

Can someone help me with that? :)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can get information about hovered points by using `mouseOver` event or `tooltip.formatter`

Example for getting multiple points information when tooltip is `shared`:

```
 tooltip: {
    formatter: function() {
      let tooltip = this.points.reduce(function(s, point) {
        return s + '<br/>' + point.series.name + ': ' +
          point.y + 'm';
      }, '<b>' + new Date(this.x) + '</b>');

      inf.innerHTML = tooltip;
      return tooltip;
    },
    shared: true
  },
```

**Demo:**

https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/veqj67yf/

https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/quympake/

**API Reference:**
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.point.events.mouseOver
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.formatter